# Studio Flow -> Send Message -> Function (Email)

Tags: twilio, sms, sendgrid, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

Looking for some help here. Not a coder by any means and trying to use built in functionality of Twilio to do 2 things.  My goal is to respond to any SMS that is received on any of my numbers and then forward the received message to an email distro.

I have easily accomplished both of these separately.

Using a studio flow I setup an auto-responder and then using a function I integrated into SendGrid to send an email of the SMS.  But when I try to combine the 2 it keeps failing.

My first approach was to call the function after the send message widget in studio but that errors out.  Below is a pic of the flow and the errors.

[image: STUDIO FLOW]

[image: ERRORS]

My second approach was to just add some type of auto-respond section to my send to email function but I am no coder and cannot find any examples of anyone else doing it this way. I am just using the auto-deployed code for twilio and sendgrid integration for this function but code is below.

[image: SEND TO EMAIL CODE]

Any ideas??

Thanks,
Drew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's hard to tell, but my guess here is that you have not passed the necessary data from the Studio Flow to the Function. The Function code you have there expects the `event` object to have a `From` and `Body` parameter, which is normally passed to it by the [incoming SMS webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request).

When you use the Function as a widget in Studio, you need to pass those bits of data yourself. In this case, you should pass a parameter called `Body` with the value `{{trigger.message.Body}}` and a parameter of `From` with the value `{{trigger.message.From}}`, like this:

[image]

Comment: I will give this a try here in a bit!

Comment: Awesome!!! this worked.  Which now looking back at this makes a TON of sense.  But I was unable to pull that from the logs.  I did have another issue and that is by default the Function is in Private mode.  I was able to put it into Public mode and it worked.  But ended up putting it into Protected mode so no one else can utilize it since it requires a signature header.

Comment: Glad that's sorted! And yeah, I'd recommend protected mode for this function.